Issue with Jetty migration from 11.x to 12.x with my application
I had recently shifted to Jetty version 12.x because the JDK that was being used in my application was 21. While trying to start the application I faced an error there which was due to some problem in configuration with my rewrite-rules.xml file present in the "Jetty\Jettybase\etc."
The target that was present in the Version 11 for the same file was something like:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RuleContainer">
    <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                <Set name="name">Strict-Transport-Security</Set>
                <Set name="value">max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains</Set>
            </New>   
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>

Now using the same with Jetty 12 does not work. Can anyone please help with achieving the same functionality in the upgraded version. What am I supposed to change here. There is not much information available on the Jetty migration guide and the rewrite module in general as well(with respect to the xml configuration of the module).
So please let me know if anyone has encountered the same or faced a similar problem while migrating to the newer version.
THANKS :)
Tried changing the target in multiple ways but nothing really worked out.
